# I want to use network class for handling success and errors of servers, which is the best 3rd party for this?

Tags: ios, flutter

In flutter what's the best library for network?

I am new to Flutter previously I used Alamofire and AFNetworking in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio). Working with this is pretty simple. And it also has support for interceptors, just in case you need to change something or log responses and also the transformers if you want to transform request/response before they are sent/receieved to/from the server.